# Code to Print a 6X10 Matrix with user inputs - C++

Tags: c++, matrix, vector

I am trying to program a 6x10 matrix, which is filled with the values ​​entered by the user as follows: The user enters 6 different values, and the code prints the 6x10 matrix as follows: 
[example]

[Image showing the expected result for the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SwFzS.png)

All blank space is filled with a "--" and the values ​​are inserted in an increasing way as if the matrix followed the order 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ... 60.

My question are:  How do I print a matrix with user values ​​like the image above?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Sorry Yusef, my question is: How do I print a matrix with user values ​​like the image in the question?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a nested `for()` loop. This would output the matrix, and if you include an `if()` statement, you will be able to see if the number should be output.

```
//Row
for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
{
    //Column
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; ++j)
    {
        //If there is a number in the matrix entry, display it. If not, display '--'
        if (my_matrix[i][j] != 0)
        {
            std::cout << my_matrix[i][j] << " ";
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "-- ";
        }
    }
    //Start a new line
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

The easiest way to do this would be to have a matrix of `bool`, and if the user inputs that number, change the `bool` at that address to `true`.